# Convergence of partial sum in $L^q$

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of real independent random variables on a probabolity space $(\Omega, F, P)$ such that $X_n^2 \in L^1$ and $\mathbb{E}[X_n]=0$ for every $n$. Assume $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[X_n^2]< \infty$. Put $S_n= \sum_{i=1}^nX_i$. As a classical result, we have $S_n \to S$ almost surely and in $L^2$ as $n \to \infty$, where $S=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}X_i$.

I want to prove the following inequality which is supposed to hold for every $p \in (1, \infty)$:

\begin{equation*}
        (\mathbb{E}[\sup_{n \geqslant 1} |S_n|^{2p}])^{\frac{1}{p}} \leqslant \frac{p}{p-1} (\mathbb{E}[|S|^{2p}])^{\frac{1}{p}}
    \end{equation*}

Here is my attempt:

I was able to prove that the following holds for every $t>0$:

\begin{equation*}
        P(\sup_{n \geqslant 1}S_n^2 > t) \leqslant \frac{1}{t} \mathbb{E}[S^2; \sup_{n \geqslant 1}S_n^2 > t]
    \end{equation*}

We can assume without loss of generality that $S \in L^{2p}$. Truncate with $Y_k= \chi_{\sup_{n \geqslant 1} |S_n|^{2} \leqslant k}\sup_{n \geqslant 1} |S_n|^{2}$. Here $\chi$ is the indicator function. It suffices to prove the following holds:

\begin{equation*}
(\mathbb{E}[Y_k^p])^{\frac{1}{p}} \leqslant \frac{p}{p-1} (\mathbb{E}[|S|^{2p}])^{\frac{1}{p}}
\end{equation*}

First of all, as a classical result:

\begin{equation*}
    \mathbb{E}[X] = \int_{0}^{\infty}P(X > t)dt
\end{equation*}

If $p>1$, then by a simple change of variable:

\begin{equation*}
    \mathbb{E}[X^p] = \int_{0}^{\infty}P(X > t^{\frac{1}{p}})dt = p \int_0^{\infty}t^{p-1}P(X > t)dt
\end{equation*}

We can apply this to convert the expectations to Lebesgue integrals and apply 1:

\begin{equation*}
    (\mathbb{E}[Y_k^p])^{\frac{1}{p}} = (p \int_0^{k}t^{p-1}P(Y_k > t)dt)^{\frac{1}{p}} \leqslant (p \int_0^{k}t^{p-2} \mathbb{E}[S^2; \sup_{n \geqslant 1}S_n^2 > t]dt)^{\frac{1}{p}}
\end{equation*}

On the other hand, we can do the same for the right side of the inequality:

\begin{equation*}
    \frac{p}{p-1} (\mathbb{E}[|S|^{2p}])^{\frac{1}{p}} = \frac{p}{p-1} (p\int_0^{\infty}t^{p-1}P(S^2>t)dt)^{\frac{1}{p}}
\end{equation*}

And I am stuck as I do not have a way to connect the expectation of $S^2$ with the probability and the order of $t$ does not match. As a second attempt, I notice that the inequality looks very similar to Hardy's. Observe that $\frac{p}{p-1}=\int_0^1x^{\frac{1}{p}}dx $. I was trying to use Fubini's theorem like in the proof of Hardy's but I did not end up getting anything. Hints will really be appreciated.

Thanks in advance for the help!